# Hudson close when PuTTy is closed

Tags: java, hudson, putty

Our Hudson CI server runs on the Linux box.
Every day morning I start the Hudson using the below command in the PuTTy console

java -jar /usr/lib/hudson/hudson.war &

But at the end of the day when I close the PuTTy console to shutdown my local windows PC, it also close the Hudson server.

Is there any way to run the Hudson server non stop ?

Comment: Umm, install it [as a daemon](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Hudson-ci/Installing_Hudson_Unix_Daemon)?

Comment: Or if you want to run it manually use **nohup**: `nohup java -jar /usr/lib/hudson/hudson.war &`

Comment: Many thanks for both. nohup seems to be simple and it works for me. Still Hudson crashes at time. Is there any stable way to run Hudson ?